# Python, converting tick data to OHLCs

Tags: python, pandas, forex

I was trying to convert tick data from GainCapital to OHLCs in Python but I have come up with problems

The source data link is here http://ratedata.gaincapital.com/

I have input my code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpl_finance 
from datetime import *

def conv_str_to_datetime(x):
    return(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))

df = pd.read_csv('USD_JPY_Week3.csv', names=['lTid', 'cDealable', 'CurrencyPair', 'RateDateTime','RateBid','RateAsk'], 
                 converters={'RateDateTime': conv_str_to_datetime}) # or change 'converters' to 'parse_dates=True' here

grouped = df.groupby('CurrencyPair')
ask =  grouped['RateAsk'].resample('15Min').ohlc()
bid = grouped['RateBid'].resample('15Min').ohlc()
pandas.concat([ask, bid], axis=1, keys=['RateAsk', 'RateBid'])
```

When I use `converters`, I get:

> ValueError: time data 'RateDateTime' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'

When I replace it with `parse_dates=True`, Python returns:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

I am completely baffled by this and would appreciate greatly if someone can help me make my code work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do3hU.png)
Please note in the screenshot I highlighted in red circles the differences between the display of the datetime of the same cell, it may be one of the reasons to this, but I am not sure

The first 10 lines of the file are here:

```
lTid    cDealable   CurrencyPair    RateDateTime    RateBid RateAsk
6858533811  D   USD/JPY 00:06.4 110.585 110.605
6858534097  D   USD/JPY 03:10.1 110.584 110.604
6858534127  D   USD/JPY 03:30.1 110.583 110.603
6858534151  D   USD/JPY 04:11.6 110.58  110.593
6858534284  D   USD/JPY 05:15.4 110.58  110.591
6858534287  D   USD/JPY 05:15.6 110.58  110.59
6858534316  D   USD/JPY 05:30.1 110.58  110.591
6858534335  D   USD/JPY 05:34.9 110.565 110.585
6858534342  D   USD/JPY 05:35.1 110.565 110.58
```

Comment: In order to provide a [MCVE], can you show the first few lines of the CSV file?

Comment: I wish I can upload the file directly here, but let me try uploading a pic of it

Comment: I have uploaded a pic (a link of it as Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to upload a pic directly) and noted something odd in the csv file, please let me know if you can see it. Thanks

Comment: I tried to copy and past the first 10 lines of the csv file but it doesn't look good, I wonder how I can make it look neat as in Excel

Comment: Because you pass `names`, then `read_csv` assumes there is no header and reads the first line in the file as values. As a result, `RateDateTime` cannot be converted to datetime, and this causes the error you see. Just remove the `names` argument!

Comment: PS. Do not process the CSV file with Excel before feeding it to `read_csv`. Make sure you read the original files you downloaded.

Comment: I am wondering if column formatting in Excel (to Date type instead of Number) wouldn't help?

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks! That helped, but when I run it now, Python returns this ValueError: time data '2018-08-19 17:00:06.377000000' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', I have no idea where the'377000000' came from, was it in the original file?

Comment: Hi @sophros, thanks for the help! But how do I make the date type column formatting in Excel to show seconds after minutes, Excel doesn't seem to have that built-in format or maybe I am missing something obvious, can you help?

Comment: @sophros I fixed it! Thanks so much! You are a genius!

Comment: @IanS, I fixed this problem! Thanks so much for the help! Now I will try explore more of it!

Comment: As a token of appreciation you can upvote my comment that helped you.

Comment: @sophros it seems that there was no upvote button for comments, only for answers maybe? Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow

Comment: @BernardLin: maybe when you earn a bit more reputation....